# KeychainStore doesn't provide certificates to Java on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, ssl, certificate, truststore

While researching a problem [related to Jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/2482), I found that `java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=KeychainStore` doesn't provide certificates to my Java process on Mac OS X and it can't validate TLS/SSL for any public website (and my private website with a self-signed certificate too).

Here's the example how I tested it:

```
$ cat <<EOF > A.java
public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new java.net.URL("https://google.com/").openStream().close();
  }
}
EOF
```

And here's the result:

```
$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=KeychainStore A.java
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:645)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:464)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1055)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:395)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1140)
    at A.main(A.java:3)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:629)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:464)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1055)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:395)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1140)
    at A.main(A.java:3)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:404)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:179)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 30 more
```

Any clue why this doesn't work? Did I miss something?

PS. Some information about my environment (I've tried also Java 11):

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

$ java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 2):

`KeychainStore` only gives you access to the current user's keychain. This does not include the root certs installed on the machine like `Windows-ROOT` would on a Windows machine. As far as I can tell there is no easy way to solve this. You could implement your own `KeyStore` that extracts the certs via native code or a command. See [(Java) Programmatically access SSL certificates under "System Roots" on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986355/java-programmatically-access-ssl-certificates-under-system-roots-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: This seems like a bug in either the Apple JCE provider or macOS itself.

Comment: This is indeed a bug, and fixes for the "LTS" versions of Java have been delivered recently. https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8303465

Comment: Another bug you might run into is that the provider assumes each certificate has a unique common name.  I had 3 certificates with the same common name, different thumbprint, and the provider only returns one of these (and not the one I needed it to return).